# Создание объекта класса через родителя. Python

Tags: python, ооп

Пишу калькулятор на python. У меня **есть 2 типа кнопок**: *цифры* и  *операции*. **Описал 3 класса**: класс *кнопки*(**родитель**), классы *кнопки-операции* и *кнопки-цифры*(**дочерние**).

```
class Button:
    pass

class NumberButton(Button):
    pass

class OperationButton(Button):
   pass
```

**Есть макет** калькулятора, сделанный на PyQt5, где каждая кнопка имеет имя:

а) *num0, num1, num2, ... , num9* - кнопки цифр

б) *op_plus, op_minus,  op_divide, op_multiply* - кнопки операций

**Вопрос**. Как можно вынести конструктор в класс-родителя *Button*, чтобы я, смог создавать объект класса через базовый класс, который сам бы определял, объект какого дочернего класса нужно создать?

**Хочу**:

```
button = Button(button_name)
```

**Не хочу**:

```
if button_name == num0 or ... button_name == num0:
    button = NumberButton(button_name)
else:
    button = OperationButton(button_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно как-то так:

```
class Button:

    def __new__(cls, name):
        if 'num' in name:
            return NumberButton(name)
        else:
            return OperationButton(name)
```